# Deploying Website with Migration using FTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, ftp, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have an asp.net MVC website making extensive use of ef and migrations. 
i have tried deploying it to a system running windows 10 on a local network but seems like ms has removed that options from the latest release and now deployment using web deploy is only possible on server os's.

No trying to do the same using FTP.
whats the ay to deploy using ftp on a local server. I have already setup FTP publishing but cant seem to figure out how to deploy the db and configure the app to run code first migration after every deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer in [this forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1993064.aspx?MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion) helped me out with this exact issue.  I added the code given there to Application_Start in my Global.asax.cs

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyObjectContext, MyObjextContextMigration>());
MyObjectContext contexttest= new MyObjectContext();
contexttest.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Just be aware that this will run your seed method every time you visit your site (at least it did for me).  In my configuration.cs I put in a check to see if data existed in my tables, if that data was null then it was ok to seed that table,  etc.